# How to install Composer on shared hosting for easy Deploy

Tags: symfony, ssh, composer-php, bundle, shared-hosting

I'm trying to deploy my symfony application with easy deploy bundle, however I have an error at the second step :

```
| out :: /usr/bin/git
[OK] git command exists
[localhost] Executing command: cd /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay && which ssh
| out :: /usr/bin/ssh
[OK] ssh command exists
[kublayconc@ssh.cluster028.hosting.ovh.net] Executing command: echo 2021847078
kublayconc@ssh.cluster028.hosting.ovh.net's password: 
| out :: 2021847078
[OK] The server allows to login via SSH from the local machine
[kublayconc@ssh.cluster028.hosting.ovh.net] Executing command: which /usr/local/bin/composer
kublayconc@ssh.cluster028.hosting.ovh.net's password: 

In Process.php line 254:

  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException]                                               
  The command "ssh kublayconc@ssh.cluster028.hosting.ovh.net -p 22 'which /usr/local/bin/composer'" failed.  

  Exit Code: 1(General error)                                                                                

  Working directory: /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay                                                    

  Output:                                                                                                    
  ================                                                                                           


  Error Output:                                                                                              
  ================                                                                                           


Exception trace:
  at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:254
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->mustRun() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/easycorp/easy-deploy-bundle/src/Task/TaskRunner.php:79
 EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyDeployBundle\Task\TaskRunner->doRun() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/easycorp/easy-deploy-bundle/src/Task/TaskRunner.php:38
 EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyDeployBundle\Task\TaskRunner->run() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/easycorp/easy-deploy-bundle/src/Deployer/AbstractDeployer.php:230
 EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyDeployBundle\Deployer\AbstractDeployer->checkRequirements() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/easycorp/easy-deploy-bundle/src/Deployer/AbstractDeployer.php:143
 EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyDeployBundle\Deployer\AbstractDeployer->initialize() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/easycorp/easy-deploy-bundle/src/Command/DeployCommand.php:78
 EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyDeployBundle\Command\DeployCommand->execute() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:952
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:87
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:273
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:73
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:149
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /Users/marilou/Desktop/Kublay/kublay/bin/console:42

deploy [-c|--configuration CONFIGURATION] [--dry-run] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]  [<stage>]
```

**I tried to install composer on my server but it look likes that it doesn't install at the place easy-deploy look for it**

```
Downloading...

Composer (version 1.9.1) successfully installed to: /home/kublayconc/composer
Use it: php composer

Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

PHP was compiled with --enable-sigchild which can cause issues on some platforms.
Recompile it without this flag if possible, see also:
    https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22999

kublayconc@ssh01.cluster028.gra.hosting.ovh.net (php/7.2/production/stable) ~ $ php composer
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
Composer version 1.9.1 2019-11-01 17:20:17
```

It seems like composer is well installed on the server. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in your question, EasyDeployBundle is looking for composer in a specific path. A quick search on GitHub shows where the path is set:
[src/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php](https://github.com/EasyCorp/easy-deploy-bundle/blob/f6c45c2c874ba85e0ec584a8942fd796f956a0aa/src/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php#L38)

```php
private $remoteComposerBinaryPath = '/usr/local/bin/composer';
```

Basically, what you need to do - unfortunately I don't know the bundle enough, to specifically tell you how - is to call [`$configuration->remoteComposerBinaryPath($remotePath)`](https://github.com/EasyCorp/easy-deploy-bundle/blob/f6c45c2c874ba85e0ec584a8942fd796f956a0aa/src/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php#L144-L149) and then pass it the actual location of your composer binary in `$remotePath`, e.g. `/home/kublayconc/composer`.